# Converting string to an RSA Key object

Tags: go, cryptography

I have a pair of RSA private and public key that was given in the form of a string.

`privateKey := "MIIB.......SDNW"`

`publicKey := "MIIE........io="`

I would like to use these keys for encryption and decryption but it requires them to be in an rsa.PrivateKey and rsa.PublicKey (PKCS8) object to be passed onto as an argument. How do I go about this?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/pem may help...?

Comment: There is no PKCS#8 format for public keys, only for private keys. For public keys there is the X.509/SPKI format. For RSA, there is also the PKCS#1 format for both the private and the public key. The import depends on the format, which format do your keys have?

Comment: Your keys seem to be Base64 encoded DER encoded keys. As suggested in the first comment, these could be encoded as PEM (converting Base64 encoded DER to PEM is trivial). Then you can use the [crypto/x509 package](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509) for import (using the functions corresponding to the format of your keys). I already posted links to SO posts about this in my comment to your last question.

Comment: @Topaco Ah yes sorry for the mistake, i was looking to convert the Public key to an SPKI format and the private key to a PKCS#8 format. The keys are base64 encdoded DER keys. Which package/function should i use for this?

Comment: Since there is not much difference between PEM and Base64 encoded DER, the *pem* package, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719783/9014097) for the import of an X.509/SPKI public key. You only need to add (the format dependent) header and footer.